# варианты обращения с ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Что происходит**

При нажатии на `submit` отправляются данные (после проверки естественно) на `/request.php`.

После чего происходит параметр аджакса `success` (так как все прошло успешно) и вылазит попап (`popap.bPopup`) с кнопкой `#knopka`, после нажатия на нее -> попап закрывается.

**Что нужно**

Чтобы после нажатия на `#knopka` приходило то же письмо, что и на форму только с дополнительным параметром в `data`, и если уж была нажата `#knopka`, то основное письмо `submit` тогда уже не приходило (во избежании дубляжа писем).

```
 $('.request-form').on('submit', function (e) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/request.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if ('error' in data && 0 == data.error) {
                    popap.bPopup({
                        // autoClose: 1000,
                        speed:500,
                        escClose:true,
                        modalClose: false,
                        opacity: 0.6,
                        positionStyle: 'fixed' //'fixed' or 'absolute'
                    });

                }
                else {
                    console.log(data);
                }



                $('.request-form').get(0).reset();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error(errorThrown);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#knopka').bind('click', function(){
                      popap.close();

                    });
```

Comment: что есть "письмо" в контексте Вашего вопроса?

Comment: запрос видимо он имеет в виду

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку отправляете тот же запрос на `request.php`, только с лишним параметром типа `buttonclicked=true`. Однако, если "основное письмо `submit`" уходит при первой отсылке на `request.php` (до `popap`), то остановить Вы его уже не можете.

Comment: поставьте у элемента `#knopka` `type="button"`

Answer (score 1):

> происходит параметр аджакса `success` (так как ***все прошло успешно***) и
>   *вылазит* попап (`popap.bPopup`) с кнопкой `#knopka`, ***после*** нажатия на нее
>
> **Что нужно**
>
> если уж была нажата `#knopka`, то основное письмо `submit` ***тогда* *уже не
>   приходило*** (во избежании дубляжа писем).

Это невозможно

Comment: Как, мы не можем вернуться в прошлое и предотвратить нежелательные события?

Comment: @Igor Да, наш удел - иметь дело с последствиями